# StrictHostKeyChecking=ask not working no matter what I do

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

This feels like a novice question but I cannot log into my ssh server after changing the host hey, *despite* throwing around StrictHostKeyChecking=no or StrictHostKeyChecking=ask everywhere.

The behavior I want is to be asked about mismatching key and be able to say "yes" for ssh to overwrite the known key and move on. I get the impression this used to be default behavior!

- /etc/ssh/ssh_config has no StrictHostKeyChecking (it is commented out). The default as per manual, is ask, which should be what I want
- ~/.ssh/config has no StrictHostKeyChecking configuration
- i tried setting StrictHostKeyChecking=ask and StrictHostKeyChecking=no on the commandline and the results are baffling:

With StrictHostKeyChecking=ask on the cmdline I never get asked. I'm being told the following, and connection fails:

```
ECDSA host key for localhost has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

With StrictHostKeyChecking=no on the cmdline the connection is established but crippled, saying:

```
Password authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
Keyboard-interactive authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
X11 forwarding is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
```

this is no joy, because I need X forwarding.

So to summarise - only adding the option on the cmdline seems to make the difference, but still I am not asked. Adding the option in either /etc/ssh/ssh_config or ~/.ssh/config makes no difference. Why is this? is it because I'm attempting to use X? No, even with X disabled I am not being asked. Is it because of some server-side config? (sshd)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you seem to want was never default behavior, nor did ssh ever behave this way.

Check carefully what the man page has to say about StrictHostKeyChecking:

> If this flag is set to **yes**, ssh(1) will never automatically add
> host keys to the *~/.ssh/known_hosts* file, and refuses to connect
> to hosts whose host key has changed.  This provides maximum protection against man-in-the-middle (MITM) attacks, though it can
> be annoying when the */etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts* file is poorly
> maintained or when connections to new hosts are frequently made.
> This option forces the user to manually add all new hosts.
>
> If this flag is set to “accept-new” then ssh will automatically
> add new host keys to the user known hosts files, but will not
> permit connections to hosts with changed host keys.  If this flag
> is set to “no” or “off”, ssh will automatically add new host keys
> to the user known hosts files and allow connections to hosts with
> changed hostkeys to proceed, subject to some restrictions.  If
> this flag is set to **ask** (the default), new host keys will be
> added to the user known host files only after the user has confirmed that is what they really want to do, and ssh will refuse
> to connect to hosts whose host key has changed.  The host keys of
> known hosts will be verified automatically in all cases.

Ask only asks if the host is *not known*. If the host is known and the key doesn't match, you get the error regarding the host key mismatch and the connection is aborted.

If you've intentionally changed the host key for some reason, you also need to change or remove it in your local known_hosts file, after verifying that the new key is actually correct. This is not something that ssh will ever automate because of the extreme security risk it would pose.

Comment: Makes sense. I now believe I was confused by Putty, which I think will **ask** something like "remote host identification changed, do you want to continue". So it gives an option to continue even if host key changed, and doesn't strip you of X

Comment: @haelix Putty does that? Oh, that's scary AF. I'd stop using it immediately. Now that openssh is included in Windows 10 it'll be pretty easy for most people to dump it.

Comment: @Michael Hampton Why is that scary AF?  The documentation that you quoted says that's exactly what OpenSSH should do.  OpenSSH allows connections to hosts with changed hostkeys to proceed "subject to some restrictions".  Whatever "some restrictions" means....

Comment: @deltamind106 If the host key is different, you need to _figure out why_ and do it _before_ attempting to log in to the remote host. This is necessarily a manual process that requires thought and investigation. It is possible that you are actually connecting to a different host, and it could even be that your traffic has been hijacked and you are connecting to a malicious host.